# Html Agility Pack unclosed embed, param tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-agility-pack

A try to parse embed-object tag like this:

> HtmlNode source2 = HD.CreateElement("source"); 
>   source2.InnerHtml =

```
<object width="640" height="390" ><param name="movie" value="http://videa.hu/flvplayer.swf?v=SMxjdkVDqmrfAxJz" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><embed width="640" height="390" src="http://videa.hu/flvplayer.swf?v=SMxjdkVDqmrfAxJz" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object><br /><a href="http://videa.hu/videok/jarmuvek/markoloval-tisztitjak-a-parkolot-az-SMxjdkVDqmrfAxJz"> title="fdsdf sdf">dsdfs fs dfsd fsd </a>n here.
```

The problem is when I try the document code `HD.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` or `source2.InnerHtml` the param and embed tag will be unclosed.

I tried

> HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["param"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

but get an extra close tag.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 document.LoadHtml(loadhtmlstring);
 document.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
```

When you load the html in to the HtmlDocument try to fix the html tags. then you can solve you problem. that is allow to automatically fix the tag errors of the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but not working. It is still unclosed. I tried HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["param"] = HtmlElementFlag.Empty | HtmlElementFlag.Closed; but it is also not working